# Backbone.js adding two different models to same collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I am writing a checklist application with jQuery and Backbone.js for the first time (newbie), which allows the user to create both labels and checkbox items, such as:

Some label A

[ ] Checkbox item 1

Some label B

[ ] Checkbox item 2

I would like some critique on the code, because I feel like I'm doing it wrong and it is turning into spaghetti and not working with local storage.

First, in the view's initialize function()

```
this.listenTo(checklist, 'add', this.renderItem);
this.listenTo(checklist, 'add', this.renderLabel);
```

Then, one of the render functions for the checklist item:

```
renderItem: function(listItem) {
    if( !addingItem ) return;

    listItem.id = 'item' + checklist.length;
    var itemView = new ListItemView({model: listItem, id: listItem.id});

    // html to append
    listItem.htmlToAppend = '<input type="checkbox" id="' + listItem.id+ '"/><label for="'+ listItem.id + '">' + listItem.get('title') + '</label>';

    $(this.el).find('.list').append(listItem.htmlToAppend);
    listItem.existing = true;
    console.log(listItem.existing);
    $('[type="checkbox"]').checkboxradio(); // jQuery re-render
},
```

The problems I'm having are that:

- I want to add two different types of models (checklist items and checklist labels) both into the same model (checklist), and either one will trigger both of the 'add' events. To prevent that, I had to set the addingItem flag based on how the user enters it, but I feel like this is a poor way to do it
- I'm vaguely aware that you can have those <%= %> blocks in the HTML to load the models instead of appending on the HTML the old-fashioned way; I was also going to use Underscore templates (having the  thing in my index.html page instead) but since I need a different id for each item/label model, I don't know how to work around either
- As a result of the above mentioned problems, or some other problems I'm not aware of, I am unable to use Backbone-localStorage to fetch() the checklist collection and render it on refreshing, though I can see that the collection exists using the Chrome Javascript console

P.S. The full code is [here](https://github.com/garytse89/jQuery-Checklist/blob/b20cb5cf3383d26ef455b0ed1a18c23b9fb810d1/www/js/main.js) which I wrote based off the [Backbone Todo example](http://backbonejs.org/docs/todos.html).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you are trying to do, i will answer your doubts 1 by 1.

1. A Backbone Collection is a collection of models where the each model has to be same, you cannot add two different models in one Collection.
   So, you should create a separate backbonce collection for each of your model and bind event listeners for add event on both the collections to two separate function.

You can reduce the code repeatition using a common function which is called by both the event listeners and passes the collection name and list item to be added as arguments to the common function.

1. You can make your id's dynamic using underscore template function too.
   All you have to do is add a template variable for id and give the value after you have processed and generated the dynamic id.
2. With two separate collections you should be able to use fetch method on each collection and render the data.

I hope this info helps and I am sorry that I could not give any code examples as I am answering this from a phone application for the site.
I will add the code blocks soon.

Comment: Thanks for being clear, makes me realize I was stuck on something rather trivial but was too blinded by my own idea.